# How to list files based on the file creation and with particular error message in the file

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to list files based on the creation date and parse each file for specific error message. Then, if the file contains the error message it will display the file name. I have the following command but it does not seem to  work.

```
ls -lt|grep "Jun 18" > cat *|grep "ERROR"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: not very clear what you mean here. Do you want to select files created today and, in those, check which ones contain a given string?

Comment: Hi fedorqui, Thanks! yes, that's what I want to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are plenty of questions around explaining how to fetch files that were created today. Also, note this is [not the first question](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2888254/joie-tamayo?tab=questions) you ask and you keep missing the basics: may be good to read [ask].

Comment: Hi fedorqui, Sorry but I do not quite understand what is not clear about my question. Thanks!

Comment: It is not about what is not clear, but about you doing some research and putting some effort while asking.

Answer (score 2):

Use find and grep:

```
find . -type f -ctime -1 -exec grep "ERROR" -l {} \;
```

Using the `-l` option to grep will ensure you only print the name of the file that matched, not the content that matched it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work pretty nicely. But it might also pull files that were modified today.

```
for i in `find . -type f -mtime -1`; do grep "ERROR" $i; done;
```

This will pull all the files that were created (or possibly modified) for the current day and go through the file and echo out the lines that contain "ERROR"